# Python: mix the letter of each word and reverse

Tags: python

Given the strings `s1` and `s2` that are of the same length, creating a new string consisting of the last character of `s1` followed by the last character of `s2`, followed by the second to last character of `s1`, followed by the second to last character of `s2`, and so on (In other words the new string should consist of alternating characters of the reverse of `s1` and `s2`).

For example, if `s1` contained `hello` and `s2` contained `world`, then the new string should contain `odlllreohw`. Assign the new string to the variable `s3`.

I have done this far:

```
s3 = ""
for i in range(len(s1)):
    s3 = s2.reverse[i] + s1.reverse[i]
```

Where should I fix it?

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'reverse'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> str1 = 'hello'
>>> str2 = 'world'
>>> my_str = ''.join(y for x in zip(str1[::-1], str2[::-1]) for y in x)
>>> my_str
odlllreohw
```

...you can use `reversed()`, as well.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will work for python2

```
str1 = "hello"
str2 = "world"

for i,j in reversed(zip(str1,str2)):
     print i,j,
```

for python3 you should reverse strings individually

```
for i,j in zip(str1[::-1],str2[::-1]):
```

Comment: `zip` is not reversible.

Comment: try it and tell me. I have written it after trying it in my system

Comment: I suggest you try it.

Comment: Actually, in Python 2 it is. In Python 3, it is not.

Comment: in the question it wasn't mentioned whether its for python2 or python3. But thanks updated the info

Answer (score 1):

Following your code structure, just `reverse` the strings and add them one-by-one :

```
s1=s1[::-1]                   #reverse string s1
s2=s2[::-1]                   #reverse string s2
s3 = "" 

for i in range(len(s1)):
    s3 += s1[i]+s2[i]         #add from both strings letter-wise
```

#driver values

```
IN : s1="hello"
IN : s2="world"
OUT : 'odlllreohw'
```